# Exception cplex

Tags: java, cplex, eclipse-classpath

I am having this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init()V
    at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
    at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.<clinit>(concert_wrapJNI.java:1619)
    at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrap.setDebugWrappers(concert_wrap.java:18)
    at ilog.opl.IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(IloOplFactory.java:170)
```

I am working on windows with this classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="C:/IBM/opl/bin/x64_win64"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/IBM/cplex/lib/cplex.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="C:/IBM/cplex/bin"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/IBM/opl/lib/oplall.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `oplall.jar` and `cplex.jar` onto the classpath simultaneously. That may cause trouble.

Also make sure that path containing the CPLEX dlls is on your `java.library.path`.

Comment: I am trying to execute an OPL project for loading data from a file .mod.  I think Cplex may be not necessary. Please see comment down. Thank you very much.